# Will there be a performance issue if I put many files in a single ext4 directory?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, performance

I have a database of 250,000 tiny audio files that will grow to perhaps 500,000. I need to copy this to my Android phone's ext4-formatted internal storage.

I have discovered that some computers are unable to support such a large number of files in a single directory.

Will an Android 5.1 phone prevent me from moving 500,000 files to a single directory? If it permits this number of files, will it experience a slowdown in reading the files if they are all placed in one directory as opposed to distributing them numbered directories?

Comment: Internal storage or SD card? Your main problem here is going to be the file system, for example, FAT32 only allows 65,535 files in a single directory whereas ext4 has unlimited number of files per directory (as long as it's under the maximum, about 4.3B files per volume). Having 500k files in a folder is just bad practice, organization would be impossible without a folder hierachy of somekind.

Comment: On the internal storage. Is there any way to determine what type of file system is used on the internal storage? I cannot connect gparted via MTP to inspect it.

Comment: This will tell you the file system type: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo

Comment: I have the files numbered carefully, so they are just as easy to manage inside folders as out. I can just use `cp nn_*.mp3 outdir/` where `nn` is a prefix for all of the files that belong to a particular group. That is just as simple as `cp nn/*.mp3 outdir/`.

Comment: Be aware that most filesystems will start having performance issues once the number of files exceeds 10k per directory, if you Google around you will see that maintaining a single directory with more than 3k-4k files could impact performance. 250k will have a significant impact on performance regardless of the filesystem in use.

Comment: What is your file system as shown by the app

Comment: It seems to be using `ext4`, however, I cannot be sure as I don't know specifically where Android puts the files. It will be inside the `Android/data/*.com` directories.

Comment: Going by this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/466521/5585644), number of files may not be a problem but surely would think they're would be performance issue- though can't back that up

Comment: And going by [this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/99542), you can get a feel for the likely problems

Comment: @beeshyams I saw this one too.. and this was answered from a ftp or webserver perspective, something far more robust in this regard for file access than an Android phone. Although I can't prove or quantify it, which is why I didn't give a real answer, I believe that having 250k files in a single directory on Android could result in serious performance issues. They notes on a server it could increase access times by seconds, on an Android device it would likely be many times more of an issue... But like I said, I don't have no way to prove this theory.

Comment: @acejavelin: Quite agree and I am little surprised that Google doesn't throw up much when it comes to Android, perhaps unusual use case